# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

I am running into following error with below piece of code, basically below is what I am trying to do, how can I modify my code without changing the original goal...

1. if any of the values is a key with no values remove that line from the input
2. if any of the values is a key with values, for each value (which is key) recursively check for its values until there are none and remove the duplicate lines...a sample input and output is shown below:

   ```
       KEY    VALUES
       353311
       344670 
       332807 353314
       338169 334478
       334478 123456 34567
       123456 98670
       34567  11111  
       353314 353311
       348521 350166 350168 350169 350170 
       350166 348521
       350168 348521
       350169 348521
       350170 348521

       EXPECTED OUTPUT
       344670
       332807 353314 353311
       338169 334478 123456 34567 98670 11111
       348521 350166 350168 350169 350170
   ```

   Code:-

   ```
   from collections import OrderedDict
   def main ():

       with open('gerrit_dependencylist.txt') as f:
           dic = OrderedDict()
           seen = set()
           for line in f:
               #print dic,line
               spl = line.split()
               #print "SPL"
               #print spl
               if len(spl) == 1:
                   key = spl[0]
                   v = ''
               else:
                   print "LINE"
                   print line
                   key, v = spl[0], spl[1:]        
               for value in v:
                   if value in dic and dic[value] == [""]:
                       del dic[v]
               for k1,v1 in dic.iteritems():
                   if key in v1:
                       dic[k1].append(v)
                       break
               else:
                   dic[key] = [v]
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```

OUTPUT:-

```
    LINE
    332807 353314

    LINE
    338169 334478

    LINE
    334478 123456 34567

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tesst.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "tesst.py", line 21, in main
    del dic[v]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 67, in __delitem__
    dict_delitem(self, key)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `v` in this expression:

```
key, v = spl[0], spl[1:]
```

is a list with the remaining values. You cannot use a list to index a dictionary, so this:

```
del dic[v]
```

will fail. Looking at the code logic, you probably want to do this anyway:

```
for value in v:
   if ....
       del dic[value]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to index the dictionary using a list as a key.  Replace the line in the error, `del dic[v]` with `del dic[value]` - assuming that's what you meant.